# Unset WooCommerce checkout fields based on cart items quantities

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

Based on the quantity of three different products (array), I need to unset different checkout fields.

Problem is, no matter how and what I try using the code below - I get the "critical error" on website.

I need to check:

- If the quantity of any of the three products within the array is 8 or more, remove country and state (billing and shipping).
- If the quantity is less than 8 for any of the three products within the array, remove all fields except for name, phone and email (billing and shipping).

**This is the code:**

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'remove_cheeckout_fields_based_on_product_qty' );
function remove_cheeckout_fields_based_on_product_qty( $fields ) {

    $targeted_ids = array( 123, 456, 789 ); // how do I add qty to these?

    $found = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
    
        if (array_intersect( $targeted_ids, array( $item['product_id'], $item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {

    $found = true;

    break;

        }
    }
    
    if ( $found ) {
    
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_state']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);

    } else {

    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_company']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_city']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_state']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "critical error" you're getting is because your else statement was not applied correctly.

To get cart items quantities, you could use `WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities()`

Operates as follows:

- If the quantity of any of the three products within the array is 8 or more, remove country and state (billing and shipping).
- If the quantity is less than 8 for any of the three products within the array, remove all fields except for name, phone and email (billing and shipping).

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // The targeted product ids, multiple product IDs can be entered, separated by a comma
    $targeted_ids = array( 123, 456, 789 );
    
    // Required minimum quantity
    $minimum_quantity = 8;
    
    // Flag, default = false
    $flag = false;
    
    // Loop trough cart items quantities
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities() as $product_id => $cart_item_quantity ) {
        // Product ID in targeted IDs?
        if ( in_array ( $product_id, $targeted_ids ) ) {
            // Greater than or equal to
            if ( $cart_item_quantity >= $minimum_quantity ) {
                $flag = true;
            }

            // Break loop
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $flag ) {      
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] );
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_state'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_country'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_state'] );
    } else {        
        // Unset
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'] );
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] );
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'] );
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2'] );
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] );
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_state'] );
        unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_city'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_country'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_state'] );
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] );
    }    

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
```